# Writing hql file in bat script

Tags: sql, unix, batch-file

```
echo select location, AVG(age) as average from location where location='%name%' >test.sql
```

When I dwant to write a simple sql script to a file, I get the error "AS was unexpected at this time" so when I remove as, I get "FROM was unexpected at this time". It works when I surround the statement by double quotes, but I don't want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the `()`

```
echo selecet location, AVG^(age^) as average from location where location='%name%' >test.sql
```